# Securing and accessing a .NET core WebApi service using OAuth2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a working Asp.NET core WebApi service and a that can be called from an ASP.NET core MVC application. The service is called using an AutoRest generated wrapper. The service currently has no security layer while the website is secured using OAuth2.

I have added the following to the service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();

        // NEW Authorisation
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiAccess", policy => policy.RequireClaim("email"));
        });

    }
```

My Controller is secured so:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ApiAccess")]
public class StatusController : Controller
```

However I get an "Unauthorized" exception when I call the AutoRest wrapper:

```
try
        {
            var service = new StatusAPI(new Uri("http://localhost:17237/"));
            ViewData["State"] = service.ApiStatusGet();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewData["State"] = new[] { new ServiceStatus { Name = "Health API", Message = "Is unreachable " + ex.Message } };
        }
```

I'm not sure if the problem lies in that I need a way to pass on the claims in my call to the wrapper or if its in my setup of the service and how it detects the claims.

Comment: Is there an authentication middleware or some custom code that fill the email claim in the principal?

Comment: Ideally I'm looking for an example showing how things need to be configurued

Comment: I don't see you supplying any type of token that would contain the email claim. Is this something that `StatusAPI` takes care of for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please try specifying the value of the claim like the allowed email address. As suggested here - https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html

Repeated the code

> `options.AddPolicy("Founders", policy =>
>                             policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"));`

Comment: As far as I know that simply restricts the valid value of the claims, and as far as I can tell I don't have any claims coming through

Answer (score 0):

Autorization cannot be done without authentication.
You need to authenticate the user first, then looks at its identity for granting access.

If you have a JWT provided by your OAuth2 AS, you may use the JWT authentication middleware.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // add the authentication dependencies
  services.AddAuthentication();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
  {
     // configure your JWT authentication here
  });
}
```

Of course the JWT should contains a "email" claim.

You can look at the ASPNET Core sample :
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/JwtBearerSample/Startup.cs#L67